# How to run a simple project created with yarn

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, yarnpkg

I'm an Angular/Typescript developer, but not very experienced with web build tools. I have come across a situation in which I would like to build a simple project in Typescript using yarn to provide me some dependencies (in other words, without using the Angular CLI or another framework's CLI). My plan was to write a simple Typescript file containing some code using a library added to the project with yarn, transpile that file and include it into a simple HTML page. To make sure all modules were referenced correctly in the transpiled code, I would use webpack to make a bundle. The simple HTML page to show the script results would be the index.html served by webpack-dev-server, then, naturally (as an Angular developer).

That means when I want to build my project I'm running the following commands on the command line, where issuewithturf.ts is meant to be the entry point code file for my project:

```
tsc ./issuewithturf.ts
webpack --mode development ./issuewithturf.js
webpack-dev-server --mode development ./issuewithturf.js
```

The main Typescript file issuewithturf.ts looks like this:

```
import { Feature, Polygon } from '@turf/helpers';
import { intersect as intersectTurf } from '@turf/turf';

let viewPolygon: Feature<Polygon> = {
    type: "Feature",
    properties: {},
    geometry: {
        type: "Polygon",
        coordinates: [[[ -70.47089614661226, -288.9575708753425 ], [ -89.01875849383576, -29.215166767389463 ], [ 87.55196076382538, 297.16069587534249 ], [ 89.87816973489422, 37.41829176738939 ], [ -70.47089614661226, -288.9575708753425 ]]]
    }
}

let areaPolygon: Feature<Polygon> = {
    type: "Feature",
    properties: {},
    geometry: {
        type: "Polygon",
        coordinates: [[[ 51.2898777767907,  4.268278231777 ], [ 51.289859436277, 4.2682590621057 ], [ 51.2898293706702, 4.26833214844409 ], [ 51.2898477111839, 4.26835131811539 ], [ 51.2898777767907, 4.268278231777 ]]]
    }
}

function intersect(polygon1: Feature<Polygon>, polygon2: Feature<Polygon>): number[][] | undefined {
    let intersection: Feature<any> | null = intersectTurf(polygon1, polygon2);
    if (intersection !== null && intersection.geometry !== null) {
        let coos: number[][] = intersection.geometry.coordinates[0];
        return coos;
    }
    return undefined;
}

console.log(`Intersection = '${intersect(viewPolygon, areaPolygon)}'`);
```

This is the index.html that webpack-dev-server is serving:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Issue with turf test</title>
    <script data-main="./issuewithturf.js" src="./require.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Look at the console</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

(Looking at the transpiled file from Typescript made me I assume I needed RequireJS, so I added require.js to my project directory and added the package requirejs with yarn)

Now, I don't know what I'm doing wrong or missing in this workflow, but when I surf to the URL webpack-dev-server indicates the only thing I get in my console is the following error (in Firefox):

```
ReferenceError: exports is not defined (issuewithturf.js:2:1)
```

For your convenience, here is that transpiled file issuewithturf.js's contents:

```
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
var turf_1 = require("@turf/turf");
var viewPolygon = {
    type: "Feature",
    properties: {},
    geometry: {
        type: "Polygon",
        coordinates: [[[-70.47089614661226, -288.9575708753425], [-89.01875849383576, -29.215166767389463], [87.55196076382538, 297.16069587534249], [89.87816973489422, 37.41829176738939], [-70.47089614661226, -288.9575708753425]]]
    }
};
var areaPolygon = {
    type: "Feature",
    properties: {},
    geometry: {
        type: "Polygon",
        coordinates: [[[51.2898777767907, 4.268278231777], [51.289859436277, 4.2682590621057], [51.2898293706702, 4.26833214844409], [51.2898477111839, 4.26835131811539], [51.2898777767907, 4.268278231777]]]
    }
};
function intersect(polygon1, polygon2) {
    var intersection = turf_1.intersect(polygon1, polygon2);
    if (intersection !== null && intersection.geometry !== null) {
        var coos = intersection.geometry.coordinates[0];
        return coos;
    }
    return undefined;
}
console.log("Intersection = '" + intersect(viewPolygon, areaPolygon) + "'");
```

I am really at a loss here and would really appreciate if someone could explain what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance,
Joshua

Answer (score 0):

I have been to quick to post this question. The problem was simply that I did not reference the bundle generated by Webpack but just the transpiled version of my script in the index.html file.

Comment: Maybe you can delete the question?

Comment: I'm not sure whether that is appropriate here

Comment: My comment or deleting the question? Since it was a simple mistake, I thought question serves no purpose.